# Azure Pipeline Resource Branch

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

EDIT: Please ignore the parts about `tags` -- as one of the answers noted, this came from a design doc and has not been fully implemented. I'm primarly concerned about the `branch` property.

---

#### Question

How do the pipeline resource `branch` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines)) and `tags` ([found on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-resources.md) but not the docs) properties work? The `version` property correctly selects the default version of a resource, but `branch` and `tags` appear to do nothing.

I expect `branch` to similarly default to the latest run with that branch as the source, and `tags` to default to the latest run with those tags. Is it broken or am I misunderstanding the behavior?

#### Test

I have two pipelines to run in series:

- Test-Build runs on master trigger or manually and publishes an artifact (tried both Build and Pipeline artifacts)
- Test-Release has a Test-Build pipeline resource

Now I tried 3 different tests:

1. Specify the `version` property on the resource. Success: Resource correctly chooses that version.
2. Specify the `branch` property on the resource. Failure: [default resource will be the latest, even if from a different branch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa8Ce.png)
3. Specify the `tags` property on the resource. Failure: default resource will be the latest, even without those tags.

#### Sample Files

Test-Build

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Test-Release

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: TestBuild
    source: Test-Build
    branch: master

jobs:
- deployment: TestDeployment
  environment: Test
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo Deploying!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of testing, I think I actually figured this out.

I believe it's purely a UI bug. The UI will show the latest build selected, even if it's from a different branch. However, if you proceed to run the pipeline without manually changing the selection, then it will correctly use the latest build from the correct branch, despite it having shown a different default selection in the UI.

And as Leo Liu-MSFT pointed out, the `tags` property came from a design doc and hasn't been fully implemented yet.

I opened an issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1116614/pipeline-resource-branch-filter-shows-incorrect-de.html) with a full recorded demonstration of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Pipeline Resource Branch

Indeed, I could also reproduced this issue on my side. That because that document is a **Design** Docs.

You could check the **title** of [that doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-resources.md):

[image]

> The design docs within this repo are created at different times during
> the development of Azure Pipelines, to support collaborative
> contributions to the design process. Designs documents are for,
>
> - **features considered for implementation but never implemented**
> - already implemented features
> - **future ideas for features**
>
> **The design docs in this repo may not represent the current state of an Azure Pipelines feature**.

**Obviously**, this is a function that has **not yet been fully implemented**. That the reason why you could not get that work. You can expect it to come, I believe it will meet us soon.

**Update:**

I tested this `Branch` feature, but there seems to be a gap between what we expected.

At the beginning, I got the same result as you. Default resource will be the latest, even if from a different branch. Then I check the document again, found that:

> When you define a resource trigger, if its pipeline resource is from
> the same repo as the current pipeline, **triggering follows the same
> branch and commit on which the event is raised**. But if the pipeline
> resource is from a different repo, the current pipeline is triggered
> on the default branch.

> Default branch for triggers
>
> Triggers for resources are created based
> on the default branch configuration of your YAML, which is master.
> However, **if you want to configure resource triggers from a different
> branch, you need to change the default branch for the pipeline.**

So, to make it work. I have create two Test-Release yml file for different branches:

Master branch:

```
trigger: none

    resources:
      pipelines:
      - pipeline: TestBuild
        source: Test-Build
        branch: master
```

Dev branch:

```
trigger: none

    resources:
      pipelines:
      - pipeline: TestBuild
        source: Test-Build
        branch: Dev
```

And we have to manually to change the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds for the pipeline `Test-Release`:

[image]

In this case, we could make the Branch feature works fine.

Comment: The first link to the docs that document the `branch` property is an official docs page, not a design doc. (The reason I included the `tags` property in this question was because it seemed like the online yaml editor had syntax validation for this property, but if it's not implemented, please still answer about the `branch` property.)

Comment: @JonathanNoyola, Yes, I also have the same doubt as you. But I always get the same result as you, I once doubted whether this function was not fully implemented. After spending a lot of time researching this problem, I found that this function seems to be a certain gap from our expectations. You could check my updated answer for some more detailes.

Comment: I don't understand how a second pipeline for a different branch will help. Even for my single pipeline, which has `branch: master` and the "Default branch" set to "master", when I create a manual release it still picks the latest build _even if it's not from master_. I'm just trying to emulate [this behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources) of choosing the "latest from specific branch" by default.